# Memory usage and order of complexity of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, object, memory, asymptotic-complexity

JavaScript objects are easy to use as hashmaps as they are essentially just a collection of key/value pairs. I am concerned with the memory usage and the time cost of storage and retrieval.  I guess that the answer to this differs with the implementations of JavaScript engines.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) links to the [Wikipedia hashmap article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) but what I don't know is how big the hash table is for an object.

So what I want to know is, how expensive are objects in memory and how often is storage/retrieval an O(1) operation and how often is it an O(n) operation?

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the particular JavaScript engine that you're using.

V8, for instance, in the simplest case translates a hashmap to an array and stores it a single block of memory.

Why?

Because it's faster to access an array element given an offset than a hashtable for obvious reasons.

Source:
http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation

I hope this answers your question at least partially :)